# How to Load More JSON Data when scrolling page to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, scroll

Dynamic load data on scroll
I am working on a web application, where we need to show more than 200 rows in a single page.

What is the best way to achieve this? As per requirements, we cant use pagination. We are looking at options like Live Scrolling in Adobe Flex..is there any other framework that helps in doing this job efficient and easy???

Thanks in advance.
How to Load More JSON Data when scrolling page to bottom ???? 
Like Infinite Scroll or something similar 
My .JS

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to reduce your question to something more specific. I can't tell whether you're asking how to modify your code or what plugin to use.

Comment: This blog may be used for you https://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2018/06/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many jquery plugins that can be used for using infinite scroll effect with pagination. you can use following plugins.

- [jquery ias](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/examples/basic/page1.html)
- [infinite-ajax-scroll](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll)